# Computing the sum $\frac{8}{5}+\frac{16}{65}+\frac{24}{325}...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

After some amount of trial and error, I realised that the denominator was of the form $4k^4+1$. So I rewrote the expression as,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{8k}{4k^4+1}
$$
Now I am unable to convert this into a form which can be simplified easily. How should I proceed further? Also, is it possible that the pattern in the denominators is different from the one that I have guessed?

Comment: Partial fractions?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I did try that but I am not able to make my way after that..

Comment: I wouldn't jump to a quartic to explain the sequence $5,65,325$.  I mean, they could also be values of the quadratic $100 n^2 - 240 n + 145$.  Three terms isn't a lot to work with.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{4k}{4k^4+1}=\frac{1}{2k^2-2k+1}-\frac{1}{2k^2+2k+1}.$

Comment: $$4k^4+1=(2k^2+1)^2-(2k)^2=?$$

Comment: bc gets me very close to 2 in 100 terms. Even closer in 1000. So my vote is that the sum is $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$\begin{align}\frac{8k}{4k^4+1}&=\frac{8k}{\left(2k^2-2k+1\right)\,\left(2k^2+2k+1\right)}\\&=\frac{2}{2k^2-2k+1}-\frac{2}{2k^2+2k+1}\\&=\frac{2}{2k^2-2k+1}-\frac{2}{2(k+1)^2-2(k+1)+1}\,.\end{align}$$

Comment: Indeed telescopes to $2$.

Comment: What path should I take to realise that the denominator could be written in this manner?

Comment: Factorize the denominator, always!  Then, see if the denominator can be written in the form $p(k)\,p(k+1)$ for some reasonable function (most likely a polynomial) $p$.

Comment: @Vishal, $\frac{2}{2k(k-1)+1}-\frac{2}{2k(k+1)+1}$ can help as well.